# How to write java wrapper classes for interaction between web application and CP-ABE tool (which is in C language)

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, amazon-ec2, cryptography

I installed CP-ABE tool in EC2 instance and i need java wrapper classes  to interaction between CP-ABE tool and web application. How should i proceed from creating web application and wrapper classes.

Help me

Comment: There's javacpp that allows to wrap C++ but to be honest. Why do you want to use a C++ library. Isn't there a java alternative like bouncy castle or something like this.

Comment: You really don't want to write wrapper classes for Bethencourt's cpabe using JNI. Why don't you just use [JCPABE](https://github.com/TU-Berlin-SNET/JCPABE)? Note that you can also directly execute tools through `Runtime#exec` or similar, then you wouldn't have to wrap C/C++ code, but can use the executables directly.

Comment: After implementing jcpabe in Amazon EC2(ubuntu instance).  how to upload encrypted file into Amazon S3 and download file for decryption.